# How to modify element style attribute using ERB and JQuery with a % sign in value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to modify the `style="width: 5%"` attribute of a span using Jquery and ajax. The width needs to be a percentage value as it represents a progress bar.

In my html.erb I have:

```
  <div class="progress success round">
    <span class="meter" style="width: <%= @project.progress %>%"></span>
  </div>
```

in my js.erb,  I have:

```
$('.meter').css("style", "width: <%= @project.progress %>%");
```

The result of this is replacing the span with the number value of @project.progress as plain text without a wrapping element (gets rid of the span).

I tried escaping the javascript as follows, turning the @project.progress into a string because j performs a gsub:

```
 $('.meter').css("style", "width: <%= j@project.progress.to_s %>%");
```

i get the same result. 
My feeling is the % sign is messing stuff up, not sure how to work around. 
Help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you do it in general.
`$('.meter').css("width", value + "%");`

I do not recognize all of your syntax, but I guess the exact code you are looking for is:
`$('.meter').css('width', '<%= @project.progress %>%');`

Comment: thank you for attempt, i've tried that as well, same result. the entire span is replaced with the number value of @project.progress in plain text

Comment: Then your problem has to be that you are using the `<`.